# Python rrdtool.create()

Tags: python, rrdtool, rrd

I have a RRD database that I am trying to create, and I have a couple loops written to build the command, which works fine, and produces the expected output.  The problem arises when I actually try to run the rrdtool.create command in Python.  This loop produces a string, we will call it `rrdStr`, containing the following:

```
'"0x04.rrd", "--step","5",
"DS:TEMP:GAUGE:10:0:100",
"DS:HUMIDITY:GAUGE:10:0:100",
"DS:LIGHT:GAUGE:10:0:1024",
"DS:POT:GAUGE:10:0:1024",
"RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:17142",
"RRA:MIN:0.5:1:17142",
"RRA:MAX:0.5:1:17142",
"RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:7200",
"RRA:MIN:0.5:12:7200",
"RRA:MAX:0.5:12:7200",
"RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:60:8640",
"RRA:MIN:0.5:60:8640",
"RRA:MAX:0.5:60:8640",
"RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:360:17532",
"RRA:MIN:0.5:360:17532",
"RRA:MAX:0.5:360:17532"'
```

All the quotes and newline characters are escaped correctly as far as I can tell.

If i pass the `rrdtool.create` the string variable like this: `rrdtool.create(rrdStr)`, I get the output

```
rrdtool.error: you must define at least one Round Robin Archive
```

But, if I copy and paste the above output directly into the `rrdtool.create()` function, it works like it is supposed to, and creates the database.

Any idea what causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.  Rather than creating one long string that contains all of the commands correctly formatted, you must create a list, each line of the rrd command is added to the list as the command is generated.

The command above becomes:

```
rrdStr = ["0x04.rrd", "--step","5"]
rrdStr += ["DS:TEMP:GAUGE:10:0:100"]
rrdStr += ["DS:HUMIDITY:GAUGE:10:0:100"]
rrdStr += ["DS:LIGHT:GAUGE:10:0:1024"]
rrdStr += ["DS:POT:GAUGE:10:0:1024"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:17142"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:MIN:0.5:1:17142"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:MAX:0.5:1:17142"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:7200"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:MIN:0.5:12:7200"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:MAX:0.5:12:7200"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:60:8640"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:MIN:0.5:60:8640"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:MAX:0.5:60:8640"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:360:17532"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:MIN:0.5:360:17532"]
rrdStr += ["RRA:MAX:0.5:360:17532"]
```

You can then pass the list as the only command `rrdtool.create(rrdStr)` The same command that failed before will then run successfully

Answer (score -1):

use rrdtool.create(*rrdStr) on python2.6 rrdtool-python-1.3.8-6.el6.x86_64